# Magento 2.3 mini cart is not reset when remove item programmatically

Tags: magento-2.3

Current Im using magento 2.3

I made a plugin into \Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart aroundRemoveItem() Function.

For example I added Product A (qty 1) and Product B ( qty 1 ).
When I remove A, then aroundRemoveItem() Function will help me to remove B programmatically which will make the cart empty.

Tested works fine in checkout/cart page.

But When I do remove A in mini-cart, It turns out to empty the cart, but seems like the cart section is not reset, so mini cart still show number 1 ( which is B ) and an empty cart.

This error still occured even when I try to refresh the page.

My Question is how can I make the mini cart know that the B is removed?

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue.

When sidebar->updateQuoteItem() is called, I made the 2nd call to save() function.
That's make the data on quote's going wrong.

Solution: try to save just only one.